# SES- Configuration set Open Event

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-ses

SES have configuration set, where you can track that how many events happen to the email. It contains Send, deliver and other options. Right now Send and Delivery is option is working fine but when I use the "Open" event option I found that it sends logs of Open eventtype before I even open the mail. Also I found multiple Open events in the log line.

PS: I am using Kinesis to dump those mail with configuration header to put into S3 and I can read those mails as well.

I am not sure why it is having around 3x of the normal mails.

Any help will be appreciated.

I tried to read docs of AWS and also tried to see any other stack overflow links but nothing works here.